# Django: How to filter with the abbreviations in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project. There is a model named University which stores the University names and other details. I've a search view where I'm supposed to search the universities with full name or abbreviations. For example if there is a university with name **"University of Engineering and Technology"**, I should be able to search it with **"UET"**.

Here is my search view:

```
def search(request):
   search = request.GET["search"]
   universities = University.objects.filter(Q(name=search))
   context = {"universities": universities}
   return render(request, "company/search.html", context)
```

Comment: I think in that case you better add an abbreviation field to your model (that you perhaps automatically fill in based on the name).

Comment: Is it possible to add it automatically while adding a new university?? I mean without asking the user.

Comment: @AzmatAli You don't need to ask the user for abbreviation (even tho this should be better since not everyone abbr in the same way), you can do a `clean_data` and get the name of the uni from the form, get the first letter of each word and save to the abbr field (similar to gettting current user and save).